# force browser to auto reload post request when using BrowserSync

Tags: laravel, gulp, browser-sync

using Browsersync is extremely useful . but what if we are on a page that has recieved a `post` request . in such a page , when something changes in editor, browser will ask me to confirm reload(below quote) . 
I'm wondering if there is a way to force browser reload automatically in such situation **without asking** for reload?

> To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) method.